# Codename One UWP browser execute issue

Tags: java, browser, uwp, codenameone

I am trying to obtain the HTML contents of a BrowserComponent in CodenameOne by using this code:

```
browserComponent.executeAndReturnString("document.documentElement.outerHTML")
```

This works in the simulator, on iOS and on Android. In a UWP app executeAndReturnString never returns. Here is a runnable example (use in the start method of a new project):

```
BrowserComponent browserComponent = new BrowserComponent();
browserComponent.addWebEventListener(BrowserComponent.onLoad, evt -> {
    Log.p("onLoad start", Log.INFO);
    Log.p(browserComponent.executeAndReturnString("document.documentElement.outerHTML"), Log.INFO);
    Log.p("onLoad end", Log.INFO);
});

Form form = new Form("Browser Contents Test", new BorderLayout());
form.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, browserComponent);
form.show();

browserComponent.setURL("http://www.codenameone.com");
```

In a UWP app this is everything in the log:

```
[EDT] 0:0:1,837 - Codename One revisions: 7dd4e7d08b3442d90959477ee52a5ae8c4361b29
 
[EDT] 0:0:1,891 - onLoad start
```

I have tried the asynchronous BrowserComponent.execute methods and they do the same thing. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is possibly a bug in the UWP port as fewer people use this port and it's the one port that doesn't use webkit. Please file an issue on that here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/

Comment: @ShaiAlmog okay thank you. I have added the issue. https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3239.

Answer (score 0):

The executeAndReturnString issue has now been fixed. There was an additional issue that there is a limit on the length of the returned string. That is not fixed yet but it can be worked around with code like this:

```
browserComponent.executeAndReturnString("document.documentElement.outerHTML.substring(0, 1000)")
```